# variable not defined error in AnjularJs during third party jquery plugin

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.7

We are trying to use the third party Jquery plugin to open client view when they click on the button.
I have added

```
<script src="https://testserver.net/1/modules/cdn-latest.js"></script>
```

I have directive

```
angular.directive('fileSelector', function() {
return {
templateUrl: 'fileSelectorTemplate.html',
restrict: 'E',
scope: {},
controller: 'fileSelectorController',
controllerAs: 'ctrl',
bindToController: {
  selectionMode: '<?',
  labelI18nKey: '<',
  acceptedFileTypes: '<',
  customClass: '<?',
  disabled: '<?',
  onFileSelect: '&'
},
link: function(scope, element)  {
  element.click(function () {
    CDNView.open({
      language: "en_US",
      theme: {
        color: "#3380FF"
      },
      onSuccess: function (result) {
       
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
  });
}
 };
});
```

CDNView is in javascript which we including in the html. When I compile it is saying as 'CDNView' is not defined.

How can I integrate this angular1.7?

Regards,
Sree